# Can I boot from a Reltek sd card reader?

Tags: boot, sd-card, hp-pavilion

On my laptop, I have a RelTek sd card reader, and I would like to install ubuntu on it. But my BIOS does not have a sd card option. (And also booting from usb does not boot it.) Can I boot from this?

Comment: If your card reader is USB and you cannot boot from USB, then no.

Comment: It is not usb. Because of that... can I boot?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood you. But it still boils down to boot options. Unless you can find it or get it to appear (by upgrading your BIOS/UEFI for example), there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a setting in the BIOS which dis- / enables boot from removable media to enhance security. If your BIOS does not have such an option, I would say it's impossible to boot a live USB stick or live SD card. If you have a very "special" BIOS it would reveal the according setting only if you have a bootable media inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The card reader will be on the system's USBus. If you can't boot from USB then you can't boot from an sd card. Unless your device is very old, I would be surprised that it can't boot from USB, and therefore an sd card.

Comment: Actually on windows, my sd card reader is listed under, Memory technology devices. Not USB.